# EUCALYPTUS Set machine name using euca-run-instances

Tags: server, instance, rename, naming, eucalyptus

I have read the Eucalyptus documentation ( https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/euca2ools/3.0/euca2ools-guide/euca-run-instances.html#euca-run-instances  ) as well as searched on Google as well as in this site to following question and could not find a solution.

Is there a way to set a human readable server name when setting up a new server (currently a lengthy `UID` is arbitrarily set as the server name)?

Situation: I am setting up a specific server and the name of the instance in our `IAAS` cloud, The assigned server name is a generic `UID`.

I would like to be able to specify the instance name for a number of valid reasons but am unable to find a way to do this.

Via Command Line (will convert to script for rollout to prod):

```
euca-run-instances -n 1 -g <nameofSecurityGroup> -k <NameofValidKey> -t <instanceType  i.e. c1.medium> $<VariableHolding_InstanceID>
```

This runs successfully but the `UID` set as the Server Name is unhelpful for the users/clients/admins.

RESTATED: Is there any way to set a name for this new instance  that is human friendly?

Please advise any reasonable thoughts or suggestions.

Thank you.

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating an instance you can use euca-create-tags `instance_id --tag Name=Server` to change the **name** of the **instance**.

Comment: Forgot to mark this is the solution... sorry for the delay.